How do companies manage software versioning for tools, frameworks, etc.?
If a company is using many different software, is there a way to automate version tracking - comparing current version being used in the company and latest version released, and maybe taking actions based on end of life/support for a specific version?
When I say software, this could include things like python interpreter, Kubernetes version (AKS), Redis cache, Relational database (Postgres version).
Ideally, I don't have to manually track versioning for all these and can somehow at least compare what I am using vs what is available. After that, I can simply automate tickets based on lead time for upgrading.
How do companies manage this? Any directions are appreciated.

You might need to narrow your criteria. Using python as an example with REL 8 as the OS, you have versions 3.6, 3.8, and 3.11 included in the distribution. However, many of the extra modules are included only for 3.6 and you would have to run a pip3 install to have them available under the other versions. And, given that you may have multiple versions of python installed on any given server, how are you going to track which version is used by which application?
You then have the question of if you want to download & compile 3.12 and install every necessary module manually and on every server. If so, are you willing to do the same when 3.13 is released?
If you insist on the latest & greatest, what is your timeline for modifying code in response for deprecated or removed features? Does the company have money budgeted to re-work the application this year, knowing that the current version is still supported for the next four years?

Not about getting the latest and greatest, but I believe at some point, we would have to upgrade because of EoL/EoS and security reasons. I don't have a set approach but looking for suggestions on how this is generally done in the industry.
Are there any best practices or ways to automate to be informed on what is the successor and when is the EoL for our current version, other than having to manually track each of our tooling, services, and frameworks? Whether we actually do the upgrade -- yes, that would ofcourse depend on budget, staffing capacity, need, etc.

There are several third-party security audit tools which will check your deployed software is using a secure version - however

they often report false positives when using packages from a repo where fixes are back-ported (e.g. the RHEL and Debian models)

They may not be able to track software deployed outwith the default package mechanism


The packaging system used by your OS is your starting point. Make sure it is configured to either report or apply updates automatically, and stick to packaged software unless you really, REALLY need to source software elsewhere (and if that is the case, consider adding your own packaging and repo as a mechanism for distribution).

The OP was asking about using the latest version, not the "secure" version. Are there any tools that report problems with using a supported version that may not be the latest version?

" Are there any tools"....yes. Yum, dnf and apt are capable of reporting this, probably other package managers and audit tools too. But product recommendations are off-topic.

yum/dnf/apt/blah will report the latest version shipped with the distribution. They have no insight on the latest version supported by the authors. REL-type systems are particularly bad. REL 8 ships with PHP 7.2.24 which reached end of life in 2020. 8.3 is the latest version supported by php.net but dnf will not tell you that.

EOL with origin but supported by distributor till distribution is EOL - that's how the non-rolling distributions work.

Yes, that is how they work on non-rolling distributions by definition. But as the OP is looking for the latest released version, I don't see how dnf can be used to gather the requested data.
